# jQuery Validate error messages for elements created dynamically

Tags: jquery-validate

I am working on a form which adds up to 10 fields dynamically based on user selection. I have to validate all the dynamically added elements. Till here everything is working fine except the error messages. For example if the user does not enter field 2 value and submits the form, the error message should be "Please Enter Visitor 2's Name". If user does not enters field 3 then the error should change to "Please Enter Visitor 3's Name". I have it working all except for the messages which are showing same for all the fields. Suppose user added 5 field. All the fields show up the same error message, "Please Enter Visitor 5's Name" for all input fields.

Here is my code:

```
$('.visitors_name').each(function (key, value) {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50,
        messages: {
            required: "Please Enter Visitor "+key+"'s Name",
        }
    });
});
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use a `function` to dynamically construct and `return` a message...

```
$('.visitors_name').each(function (key, value) {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50,
        messages: {
            required: function() {
                return "Please Enter Visitor " + key + "'s Name";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/6z9Lv8pk/](https://jsfiddle.net/6z9Lv8pk/)